# comparing values of elements in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

Consider below two elements of DOM Structure

```html
<li
  class="facet sector multiselect selected"
  data-bind="click: function(data, e) { $parent.sectors.setParentSector.call($parent, data, e); }, attr: { 'class' : 'facet sector multiselect' + (Selected() ? ' selected' : '') + (Disabled() ? ' disabled' : '')}"
>
  <a
    href="***parentsector=financial-services"
    data-bind="text: SectorName(), attr: { href: Url() }"
    >Financial Services</a
  >
  <span class="count" data-bind="text: '(' + JobCount() + ')'">(62)</span>
</li>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="page-counter">1 - 25 of 62 jobs</div>
</div>
```

My Requirement is verify that `count(62)` from the first element equals the total jobs appearing in page counter element `(1 - 25 of 62)`.

I have used this solution but it didn't work:

```js
it("Verify job count of filter applied should be equal to total jobs appear in webpage  ", () => {
  let count;

  cy.searchKeyword(fdata); //ignore this code as it is not relevant to this context.

  cy.get(":nth-child(7) > .count").click();
  cy.get(".selected > .count").then(($el) => {
    count = $el.text;
    cy.log(count);
  });

  cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .row-top > .row > .col-md-12 > .page-counter")
    .contains("${count}")
    .should("be.true");
});
```

Let me know where my logic is incorrect

Comment: It could be helpful if you provided an example of the html that you are trying to write tests against.

Comment: This is incorrect `count = $el.text` it is a function not a property - use `count = $el.text()`

Answer (score 2):

That looks ok, except for a couple of things

- the `.contains("${count}")` looks like you are trying to use string template, but that needs backticks around it, so as it is it will look for `$` and `{` and `}` in the page counter. You can just use `.contains(count)`, but which number will be the right comparison - `25` or `62`?
- the value of the `count` variable in the final check will still be `undefined` because you use it too early. Either add another `.then()` around the last statement, or pass the count down the chain instead of using an external variable.

Here's some code which might be better

**Delay use of count variable**

```js
it("Verify job count ...", () => {
  let count;

  cy.searchKeyword(fdata); //ignore this code as it is not relevant to this context.

  cy.get(":nth-child(7) > .count").click();
  cy.get(".selected > .count").then(($el) => {

    count = $el.text()  // extract text
    cy.log(count);
  })
  .then(() => {

    // this nesting delays use of count variable until it has been set

    cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .row-top > .row > .col-md-12 > .page-counter")
      .invoke('text')
      .then(counterText => {

        expect(counterText).to.eq(`1 - 25 of ${count} jobs`)
        // or
        expect(counterText).to.eq(`1 - ${count} of 62 jobs`)
      })
  })
})
```

**Pass count down the chain**

```js
it("Verify job count ...", () => {

  cy.searchKeyword(fdata); //ignore this code as it is not relevant to this context.

  cy.get(":nth-child(7) > .count").click();
  cy.get(".selected > .count").then(($el) => {

    count = $el.text()  // extract text
    cy.log(count);
    return count
  })
  .then(count => {

    // passing in the count from previous command
    // so don't have to worry about using the external variable
    // too early

    cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .row-top > .row > .col-md-12 > .page-counter")
      .invoke('text')
      .then(counterText => {

        expect(counterText).to.eq(`1 - 25 of ${count} jobs`)
        // or
        expect(counterText).to.eq(`1 - ${count} of 62 jobs`)
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: I am getting the below  error  for the first soln      expected '\n                        1 - 25 of 4,772 jobs\n                    ' to equal '1 - 25 of function(n){return b(this,function(n){return n===undefined?i.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||u).createTextNode(n))},null,n,arguments.length)} jobs'
cypress/e2e/searchJob/searchbyKeyword.cy.js:51:34
  49 |         .then(counterText => {
  50 |   
> 51 |           expect(counterText).to.eq(`1 - 25 of ${count} jobs`)
     |                                ^
  52 |           
  53 |         })
  54 |     })

Comment: Just a typo, use `$el.text()`.